# Howto maintain an app for publishing to google and amazon store

Tags: java, android, amazon-appstore

I have an app already published to google play store. I like to publish it also to the amazon store. I read about the perrequisite to have a special format (4 numbers with dot) in the versionname.

How do I maintain an app (in one eclipse project) to support both stores.
For example : Do I have to change the Versionname or is there any trick ? What else to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you not simply keep the version name in the Amazon format (possibly moving it upwards from what you currently have for Google Play)? As far as I know, Play is pretty lenient with version naming.

As for maintaining separate schemes, the [Gradle Plugin for Android](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) supports multiple flavors, where you can customize everything, from version names to actual code, so you could for example avoid showing Play links in the Amazon app and the other way around, as well as potentially using different ad networks etc. I don't know what a migration path would be for this though. Gradle supports generating Eclipse projects so you might be able to continue using it.